# how i can access to object keycloak when i login with my own login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, authorization, keycloak

I'm using keycloak with react js and ,  I'm using my own login page not login page of keycloak

```
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
 const {keycloak , initialized} = useKeycloak();
```

the problem is when I try console.log(keycloak ) I found it empty this in the case  i use   my own login page   , but when i login with the page login  of keycloak I found it load

[her is when i use keycloak login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgLmK.jpg)

[and her when i use my own page login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaleV.jpg)